# Access Form Element from Class

Tags: c#, winforms

I've got a class which includes an recursive function.
This class is used in Form1.
Well, I now want this function to add items to my ListBox1 in Form1.
If this would be a normal function I would just give the value I would like to display in return, like `Listbox1.items.add(Obj.ListDirectiory());`.
What kind of possiblities are there to pass a value from my recursive function to the ListBox?

```
    public void ListDirectory(FtpClient client, string path)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (FtpListItem item in client.GetListing(path))
            {
                if (item.Type == FtpFileSystemObjectType.Directory)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Folder: " + item.FullName);
                    //This is where I want to add something to ListBox1

                    //call the function again...
                    ListDirectory(client, item.FullName); 
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("File: " + item.FullName);
                    //This is where I want to add something to ListBox1
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try one of these

---

**Solution 1** 
Use class reference

```
public class MyFunkyClass
{
   public ListBox ListBox { get; set;}
   public void ListDirectory(FtpClient client, string path) 
   { 
      // stuff
      Listbox.Items.Add(item.FullName)
      // stuff
      ListDirectory(client, item.FullName); 
   }
}

// Usage

var myFunkyClass = new MyFunkyClass() { ListBox = listBox1} 

myFunkyClass.ListDirectory(client,path);
```

---

**Solution 2** 
Use method  reference

```
public class MyFunkyClass
{    
    public void ListDirectory(FtpClient client, string path, Listbox listbox) 
    { 
          // stuff
          listbox.Items.Add(item.FullName))       
          // stuff
          ListDirectory(client, item.FullName, listbox); 
    }
}

// Usage

var myFunkyClass = new MyFunkyClass() 

myFunkyClass.ListDirectory(client,path,listBox1);
```

---

**Solution 3** 
Use Action

```
public class MyFunkyClass
{ 

    public void ListDirectory(FtpClient client, string path, Action<string> myAction) 
    { 
          // stuff
          myAction(item.FullName)
          // stuff
          ListDirectory(client, item.FullName, myAction); 
    }

}

// Usage

var myFunkyClass = new MyFunkyClass() 

Action<string> myAction = (value) => {
   listBox1.Items.Add(value);
};

myFunkyClass.ListDirectory(client,path,myAction);

// or

myFunkyClass.ListDirectory(client,path, value => listBox1.Items.Add(value));
```

---

**Solution 4** 
Use delegate

```
public class MyFunkyClass
{ 

    public delegate void MyDelegate(string value);

    public void ListDirectory(FtpClient client, string path, MyDelegate myDelegate) 
    { 
          // stuff
          myDelegate(item.FullName)
          // stuff
          ListDirectory(client, item.FullName, myDelegate); 
    }

}

// Usage

var myFunkyClass = new MyFunkyClass() 

myFunkyClass.ListDirectory(client, path, value => listBox1.Items.Add(value)));
```

---

There are many more ways of achieving this sort of thing or various combinations of the above, however that should give you a few ideas

**Update**

As Noted in the comments, solution 3 and 4 are essentially the same thing, just different syntactic sugar

Comment: Solution 3 and 4 are pretty much identical.

Comment: @Maarten, Indeed they are both are just delegates, however i thought id get a variety in there, and hope for some upvotes to get me to 1000, nudge nudge wink wink :), i might add a note about that though for clarity, thanks

Comment: All you want for Christmas is 1000 points and the ring of power?